# eigenvectors when A-lx is singular with no solution

Tags: r, linear-algebra

How is R able to find eigenvectors for the following matrix? Eigenvalues are 2,2 so eigenvectors require solving `solve(matrix(c(0,1,0,0),2,2))` which is singular matrix with no solution.

```
> eigen(matrix(c(2,1,0,2),2,2))
$values
[1] 2 2
$vectors
[,1]          [,2] 
[1,]    0  4.440892e-16
[2,]    1 -1.000000e+00

> solve(matrix(c(0,1,0,0),2,2))
Error in solve.default(matrix(c(0, 1, 0, 0), 2, 2)) : 
Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular
```

Both the routines essentially do the same thing. They find x such that `(A-lambdaI)x = 0` without finding the inverse of `A-lambdaI`. Clearly (0 1) is a solution but how I can't understand why solve did not come up with it and how do I manually solve it.

Comment: @saminny: I commented on this on your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3429676/complex-eigenvectors/3429712#3429712

Comment: thanks. I have a related question. I asked separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's using one of the algorithms listed here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_numerical_analysis_topics#Eigenvalue_algorithms

?

According to http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/eigen.html, `eigen` seems to use the LAPACK routine at  http://netlib.org/lapack/double/dgeev.f (if you have a square matrix which is not symmetric).

Note: you're right that `A - lambda * I` is singular if lambda is an eigenvalue but in order to find eigenvectors, one does need invert `A - lambda * I` or solve an equation `y = (A - lambda * I) * x` (with `y` not being the null vector). It is sufficient to find non-zero vectors `x` which satisfy

`(A - lambda * I) * x = 0`

One strategy is to find a non-singular transformation matrix `T` such that `(A - lambda * I) * T` is an upper triangular matrix (i.e. all elements below the diagonal are zero). Because `A-lambda*I` is singular, `T` can be constructed such that the last element on the diagonal (or even more diagonal elements if the multiplicity of the eigenvalue is larger than one) is zero.

A vector `z` which **only** has it's last element equal to a non-zero value (i.e. `z = (0,....,0,1)` ) will then give the zero vector when multiplied with `(A-lambda *I) * T`. So one has:

`0 = ((A - lambda * I) * T) * z`

or in other words, `T*z` is an eigenvector of `A`.

Comment: Its still not clear to me. That is what 'solve' does, it finds non-zero vectors x satisfying (A-lambda*I)*x = 0 without finding inverse (using LU/QR decomposition methods). If solve fails for (A-lambda*I), then how is eigen able to find possible values of x. They are doing the same thing isn't it?

Comment: What I can see from the help text: if you're doing

   `solve(<matrix>)`

this is asking `solve` to invert the matrix (for which there is no solution if `<matrix>` is singular as `A-lambda*I` is if `lambda` is an eigenvalue of `A`)

Let's assume that `solve` and `eigen` decompose `A` and `A - lambda * I` into a suitable product of matrices. It is after this decomposition where the two algorithms do different things: while `solve` must try invert the two parts of the product separately does `eigen` try to find non-zero vectors which give zero when multiplied with one of the product members.

Comment: (disclaimer on my previous comment: I don't know exactly what R does internally, the comment just to tries to explain a possible way of solving the problem)

Answer (score 1):

You asked for an eigen decomposition, you got an eigen decomposition.

Had you asked for `rcond()`, the condition number of the matrix, or for `kappa()`, you would have gotten the appropriate response.

For your second example:

```
> mat <- matrix(c(0,1,0,0), 2, 2)
> kappa(mat)
[1] Inf
> 
> rcond(mat)
[1] 0
>
```

For your first example, there is actually no problem:

```
> mat <- matrix(c(2,1,0,2), 2, 2)
> kappa(mat)
[1] 1.772727
> 
> rcond(mat)
[1] 0.5714286
> 
>
```

See e.g. [this previous question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3042117/screening-multicollinearity-in-a-regression-model) for more.

Answer (score 0):

They are not doing the same.
Just take a look at the wikipedia link.
And look in code for dgeev.f and you will see that a simple solve of (A-lambda*I)x=0 is not performed.